# Unchecked cast warning appears even though generic bound was specified

Tags: java, generics

I have the following generic method in my project that will return a BaseModel object dependent on the class given:

```
public <T> T getObjectfromList(Class<T> clazz) {
   for (BaseModel model : items) {
      if (model.getClass().equals(clazz))
         return (T) model;
      }

      return null;
   }
}
```

Right now I am getting a lint warning on the line `return (T) model` because it is an unchecked cast from `BaseModel` to `T`.

To work around this, I added the bound here:

```
public <T extends BaseModel> T getObjectfromList(Class<T> clazz) {
   for (BaseModel model : items) {
      if (model.getClass().equals(clazz))
         return (T) model;
      }

      return null;
   }
}
```

However, the lint warning still appears. How can I work around this?